# Eclipse DLTK central database on server

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, indexing, eclipse-pdt, dltk

We're using Eclipse (with PDT) for several projects. The main load seems to come from the DLTK indexing process, which is quite a lot resources per client.

It would offload the clients a lot if a server could perform this indexing task (DLTK indexing could be switched off).

So I wonder; is it possible to create and use a central (H2) database/repository for indexing the projects for multiple clients?

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not attempted this, it seems entirely possible to configure the H2's Connection profile to utilize an external URL. Follow [these steps for configuring H2](http://www.expressui.com/development-setup-guide-for-eclipse/) but point the connection URL from local to the server.

After transferring the database and pointing the driver's URL Connection at the server, you could disable the DLTK indexing on every machine  except the server. I also recommend you have a look at the article suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414592/disable-or-speed-up-dltk-indexing-in-eclipse-pdt).