# How many projects/folders/files can eclipse (the editor) safely handle?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I am always the first one to jump on any latest Eclipse release thinking that it would solve some of the issue that i have with slowness but i am always disappointed. The DLTK thing that keeps running, memory heap issues, internal error occurred ....

**The latest version that I have tried is KEPLER**

I know that I can close the projects that i am not using, disable validation, remove projects from the build path, hack into their myriad of codes and change settings but really?

I have to admit my workspace has only 5 projects but more than TWO HUNDRED heavy duty folders. within those folders you have for example, Drupal, Wordpress and so on..

I have used visual studio for years with 5 times as much projects without this kind of slowness but that is besides the point. Let's go back to eclipse.

looking at my settings, some people might say: why don't you create a projects for each of those folders? I tried that but the DLTK indexer keeps on indexing every projects in my workspace unless i close them. WOW!!! Create multiple workspace is out of the questions, if i have to do that i will just ignore Eclipse all together.

**My hardware is decent and I have SSD Drive and plenty of RAMs.**

What is the largest amount of projects or files can Eclipse safely handle? What about the DLTK what are its limitations?
How large is too large?
What doesn't visual studio seem to suffer from the same slowness? Is the problem java related or with the data structure? Can Eclipse handle that amount of projects?

**I know that there are a lot of moving parts and answering these questions is not black and white but why is this thing indexing even the stuffs that i am not using?**

I would like to get some opinions on how to use this editor effectively?

Comment: I have more than 40 projects in my workspace and don't have any performance problems, but I don't have dltk installed. See this previous SO question about dltk performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414592/disable-or-speed-up-dltk-indexing-in-eclipse-pdt

Answer (score 0):

While the number of projects/files is not exactly "limited" (beside the resources of the host machine), the number of open editors is.

[Eclipse 2019-09](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#close-editors-automatically) proposes by default 99.

> ### Close editors automatically when reaching 99 open editors
>
> The preference to close editors automatically is now enabled by default.
>   It will be triggered when you have opened 99 files.
>
> If you continue to open editors, old editors will be closed to protect you from performance problems.
>
> You can modify this setting in the Preferences dialog via the `General > Editors > Close editors automatically` preference.

Answer (score -1):

IDEs are slow by nature because they do a lot.

I would never use eclipse for webdev stuff like wordpress.

You should be leaving your library files outside of your main project as external folders so that eclipse discounts them. That way you can just have the files you need in your workspace.

Also, try closing the projects you aren't working on by right clicking and choosing "close project"

Personally I use vim and FTP to handle this stuff. Eclipse is nice and integrated but very chunky.

Comment: I noticed several programmers state that they use vim or notepad to code, but do you deal with a large oop project with thousand of classes without intellisense to list the properties and methods of those classes.

Comment: There are countless plugins for vim and other editors like notepad++ that have suggestions and things like intellisence. Its just not as out-of-the-box as eclipse so you have to look around.